# xml XPath count

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm working on an xml and xslt project and I have a problem; the question asked is count the number of open ports having a given number this is the path used

```
liste_hotes --)
    hote --)
        liste_ports --)
            port num_port="80" --)
                Etat etat="open"
```

```
count(liste_hotes/hote/liste_ports/port[@num_port='80']/Etat[@etat='open'])
```

Comment: An actual example could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

XML is case-sensitive: `count(expression)` is not the same as `Count(expression)`, and there is no `Count()` function.

Comment: Good. So if you want to know why it doesn't work, post a [mcve].